# Center Align Text and Right Align Image in Table Cell <td>

Tags: html, css

I would like to right align an image in a cell AND still keep the text centered in the cell. I am using a float:right on the image which displays it correctly, however it pushes the text to the left the width of the image so it is no longer centered. Is there a way to keep the text centered?

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:center" width:"100">text
     <img src="~/images/pencil1.png" height="25" width="25" style="float: right;" />
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No, even with float the image still takes up space to you might want to re-think your strucuture

Comment: You will have to absolutely position your image if you want your text to be aligned to the center. However, your structure is not correct as @paulie_d has pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add position relative to td and position absolute to image and then, set righ=0 in the image

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:center;position:relative">    
    text
     <img src="~/images/pencil1.png" height="25" width="25" style="position:absolute;right:0" />
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Also, if you want your table become 100%, you must set the style in the table, not in the cell.

Take in mind that your text may be under the image. You can put the text over the image if you want avoid this or use a semitransparent image.

Comment: Your solution with position is the clean solution. Therefore a +1Up from me. Thanks for the comments.Merci!

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap your text and your image with a div which assigned flex. Then you can use `flex-grow: 1;`.

```css
td {
  width:50%;  
}
.tdflex {      
  display: flex;  
}

.text {
  flex-grow: 1;  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <div class="tdflex">
       <div class="text">text</div>
       <div>
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" height="25" width="25" />
       </div>
     </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**Update**

```css
td {
  width:200px; 
  height: 50px;
}
.tdpos {        
  position: relative; 
}

.tdpos img {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
.text {
  margin-top: -24px;    
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;  
}
```

```html
<table border>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <div class="tdpos">
       <div class="text">text</div>
       
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" height="50" width="50" />
       
     </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Here the text is not centered

Comment: @Victor Thank you. You are right! I updated.  Now the text is aligned. Merci!

Comment: You are welcome. I think that the question say that text must be centered in the whole cell, not in the free space after put image at right.

Comment: @Victor that is unfortunately not clear. From UX view it would be horrible if that expected. Or not?

Comment: The code of the question (apart of width problem of the cell) have the image floated at right and the text centered in the remain space. So I think that it's requesting to do that. I don't know why and I warning about that problems in my response, but I don't know all the details either. Maybe has a sense

Comment: @Victor you are correct, I wanted the text centered in the whole cell, not just the free space.

Comment: @Victor I Updated my answer. I see FlyFish confirms your suspicion. fast fix would work with position. I updated my answer and add this solution too.

Comment: @FlyFish Thank you for comment. I add this solution in my answer too. 